# Volume slider not responding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’m doing a free code camp challenge to make a drum machine that plays sounds when you click a button. I’m trying to add a volume slider that controls the volume of these sounds. I’m stuck because the volume slider doesn’t do or affect anything. I created a parent component where I initialized the volume and then added an onChange event handler. Then I passed volume as props to a child component which contains the playSound function that plays the sounds. Please help what should I change to make the slider work

```
//These are the sounds being played 

const ziki = [
  {
    keyCode: 81,
    keyTrigger: "Q",
    id: "Heater-1",
    url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3"
  },
  {
    keyCode: 87,
    keyTrigger: "W",
    id: "Heater-2",
    url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3"
  },
  {
    keyCode: 69,
    keyTrigger: "E",
    id: "Heater-3",
    url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3"
  },
  {
    keyCode: 65,
    keyTrigger: "A",
    id: "Heater-4",
    url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3"
  },
  {
    keyCode: 83,
    keyTrigger: "S",
    id: "Clap",
    url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3"
  },
 {
    keyCode: 68,
    keyTrigger: "D",
    id: "Open-HH",
    url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3"
  },
  {
    keyCode: 90,
    keyTrigger: "Z",
    id: "Kick-n'-Hat",
    url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3"
  },
  {
    keyCode: 88,
    keyTrigger: "X",
    id: "Kick",
    url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3"
  },
  {
    keyCode: 67,
    keyTrigger: "C",
    id: "Closed-HH",
    url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3"
  }
];

//This is the parent component that contains the volume variable as state 

class Drum extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { volume: 1 };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ volume: e.target.value });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 className="text-center">Drum Machine</h1>
          {ziki.map((clip) => (
            <ActualPad key={clip.id} sound={clip} volume={this.state.volume} />
          ))}
        </div>
        <br />
        <p className="text-center">
          <input
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            type="range"
            step="0.01"
            value={this.state.volume}
            min="0"
            max="1"
          />{" "}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


//This the child component where volume is passed as a prop 


    setTimeout(() => setActive(false), 500);
    audioTag.currentTime = 0;
    audioTag.volume = props.volume;
    audioTag.play();
  };
  return (
    <div
      onClick={playSound}
      className={`btn btn-secondary p-4 m-3 ${active && "btn-warning"}`}
    >
      <audio id={props.sound.keyTrigger} src={props.sound.url} />
      {props.sound.keyTrigger}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Drum />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: If you hardcode different initial volume values, does the audio play at the proper volume?

Comment: What does hardcode mean

Comment: Like, if you set the volume to 0.6 in your program (not using the slider) will it play at 60% volume

Comment: Nop it doesn’t change

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.